# How to connect android application to PC in the access point network

Tags: android, wifi

How to connect android application to PC in the access point network programmatically via IP address.
In other word, I need code to establish connection between my application and Pc, this Pc is in wifi network.

Answer (score 0):

To access your pc from the Android emulator, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064304/how-can-i-forward-my-localhost-ip-address-to-an-android-emulator) link (its 10.0.2.2). If you are using a real phone on your home network, then simply get the local IP address of your PC by opening a command prompt, and typing ipconfig /all. Then you can access it via Android. Note: this is assuming you have some open socket on your PC waiting for connections.

Comment: Also - your question is very broad. "I need code to establish connection between my application and Pc". Is your pc setup to accept socket connections? Show code examples of what you have done so far. Generally you will find on StackOverflow that no one is going to just give you code right out of the box without some attempt at it.

Comment: OK, but do I need to write code like WifiConfiguration to do the connection before opening the socket.

Comment: just I want to use of my application to send texts to server on Pc, but I need to connect to Pc programmatically instead manually.