# Local machine connection to Android Emulator

Tags: android, sockets, emulation, serversocket

Just finding answers to the other way around!

I can get my emulator to connect to my server when hosting on the local machine using IP 10.0.2.2. However it doesnt work the other way when i try to connect from the local machine to my hosting emulator.

I this case i use IP 127.0.0.1, and i get a ConnectException: connection refused. Strangely it works fine when im both hosting and using the client on the emulator.

Whats up with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I m facing the same problem. I think this is the solution however I m not able to get it to work on Linux. Here is the link 
[How can I forward my localhost IP-Address to an Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064304/how-can-i-forward-my-localhost-ip-address-to-an-android-emulator)

Comment: Thanks for forwarding this link!

Comment: Here is the solution http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28914/accessing-web-server-running-in-android-emulator-from-local-machine/28916#_=_

Answer (score 0):

```
// write in manifest file  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Start local server
  and use http://10.0.2.2/

Comment: I believe you got me wrong. Im hosting on the android emulator, and trying to connect from my java client on the local machine. Im using ServerSocket and Socket, and my manifest already got that permission