# Android emulator(client) to phone(server) socket connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

i'm currently attempting to connect emulator(client) and phone(server) through TCP/IP socket connection. But somehow it never works, but it works fine if i try to connect emulator (as client / server) with internal java program (as client / server), also socket connection works fine from phone to applications that's not on emulator. I thought it has something to do with port forwarding so I've tried:

sourced from [How can I forward my localhost IP-Address to an Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064304/how-can-i-forward-my-localhost-ip-address-to-an-android-emulator)

```
telnet localhost 5554

redir add tcp:1337:12345
```

But when i test my client side with port number 1337 and server side 12345, it still doesn't work, server code doesn't .accept() client's request.

Following is my client(emulator) and server(phone) code for accepting and setting up io streams

client:

SERVER_IP is the local ip address

```
connection = new Socket(SERVER_IP, PORT);

private void setUpStreams() throws IOException {
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        }
```

Server:

That's for accepting user
    private void acceptingUser() {

```
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(PORT, 10);
            connection = ss.accept();
            connected = true;
            osm.updateInChatStatus(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("serv", "Wasn't able to connect with any clients!: " + e);
        }
    }
```

and setting up stream is pretty much similar to the client's one. Thanks in advance for ur advices and solutions.

Comment: Are both the client and the server both on the same network? Is the phone connected to Wifi?

Comment: Yup, that's right. They are connected on the same network

Comment: try swapping, do the server stuff on the emulator and then client stuff on the phone to see if that works

Comment: @John - swapping won't work, the emulator refuses to listen on external interfaces (at least it did last time I checked).

Answer (score 0):

To access network connection, you need to set the permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bosch.adx.esidroid">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
--
```