# create 3 emulator with different IP

Tags: android, android-emulator

can i create 3 emulator with different IP  and after that  get their IP  Programmatically ? i'm working on android chat app (using Socket programming ), and i need this for test my app !

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing Port Forwarding.

Refer the below links :

[How can I forward my localhost IP-Address to an Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064304/how-can-i-forward-my-localhost-ip-address-to-an-android-emulator)

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#forwardports

Comment: what is the different between forwarding and redirecting ?

Comment: Almost same. Your Redirecting or Forwarding the request which is coming on port 5554.