# How to transmit files between two AVDs using TCP?

Tags: android, tcp, tcpclient

I have established two AVDs and would like to transfer files between them using TCP ; How do I establish this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your AVDs are running locally, they can be binded to localhost on different ports, and you can take use of Sockets.

Sockets:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

You might need to setup some forwarding stuff like below:

[How can I forward my localhost IP-Address to an Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064304/how-can-i-forward-my-localhost-ip-address-to-an-android-emulator)