# Port forwarding local server to Expo android emulator

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, expo

I have a local server running in my laptop. I want to access it via localhost in the android emulator. How can I do this?

Comment: You can find this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064304/how-can-i-forward-my-localhost-ip-address-to-an-android-emulator#:~:text=To%20forward%20a%20port%20from%20your%20local%20machine%20to%20an,Then%20select%20it%20%26%20press%20Ok.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access host machine from inside the android emulator by going to the address 10.0.2.2 inside the emulator.

For example if you have a web service accessible on `localhost:8080` on your local machine, you can access the same by typing

```
http://10.0.2.2:8080
```

from inside the emulator. More details about emulator networking you can read [in the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking)